# Java - Convert json response from python

Tags: java, json, cmd

I'm running a mail-parser (written in python) in java runtime exec:

```
ProcessBuilder processb = new ProcessBuilder("mailparser", "-f", "path to mail file", "-j");
Process process = processb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    
String s = "";
String line = "";
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    line += s;
}

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line);
```

I expect a json response but the json i get looks like this (it's not the whole json because is pritty long):

```
b'{\n  "mime-version": "1.0",\n  "x-bbounce": "251383442|3165745|name@company.co.il|97|0|1094|4",\n  "content-type": "multipart/alternative; \\n\\tboundary=\\"----E85308AFD03B4874842B50FC08B1E8C9\\"",\n  "x-received": "by 2002:a17:906:b24d:: with SM"}'
```

When I try to convert it to JSONObject I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:215)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:399)
at Test.main(Test.java:169)
```

I tried to remove to "b" and the " ' " at the beginning and the end of the json, I even tried with jsonb and it still would not work.

If I'm runnig the exact command in CMD, I get perfect json with no "b" and " ' " and I can convert it.

How do i convert this json to JSONObject?

**Edit: I dont have access to the python code**

Comment: look to your json , whole string has "\n" or "\\" ..... , You need to change your python code to generate json without pretty format .

Comment: In python, before sending JSON, add line json.loads(json_object_as_string) and send the result.

Comment: Another possibility would be to, in Python, use a dictionary and convert it to JSON at the end, with [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: In python use decode('utf-8') for the resulting json

Comment: Can you add your Python code to the question? It's giving you incorrect JSON and it's probably easier to make it return correct

Comment: Thanks for all the replies but I dont have aceess to python code

Comment: Perhaps the Python "mail-parser" has some configuration that would change this output. Is this a third-party product; either commercial or freeware? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows.

in Python, have the result built from a dictionary and return it as below:

```
example = {
  "key_a": 'value_a',
  "key_b": 'value_b'
}

print(json.dumps(example))
```

Then, in Java, you have

```
ProcessBuilder processb = new ProcessBuilder("mailparser", "-f", "path to mail file", "-j");
Process process = processb.start();
InputStream is = processb.getInputStream();
String resultString = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharset.UTF_8);
```

and from there you can convert the String to JSON.
Of course, instead of using `IOUtils::toString`, you can also use a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: That's... not great. I had to deal with such issues in the past and, when changing the source code was not possible, the only solution I could find was to very patiently clean the resulting string.  
Lots of `replaceAll` and regular expressions.

Comment: But if I run the command from the cmd like I said, I get the correct json with no "b" and the single quotes

Comment: That is strange, what does happen if you convert the InputStream to String specifying the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it is indeed a strange issue.